# Default value always display blank when bind a datasource to a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is my code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.ValueMember = "Value";
col.DisplayMember = "Name";
col.DataSource = lstParameterDataSource;
//lstParameterDataSource is lst like List<BindEntity>.
```

The `BindEntity` is a class which has two property. One property is `Value`, and the other one is `Name`. Both of them are string type.

```
this.dgvCondition.RowsAdded += delegate(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs args)
{

if (this._parameters != null && this._parameters.Count > 0)
{
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = this.dgvCondition.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
cell.Value = lstParameterDataSource[0].Value;
}
};
```

dgvCondition is my `datagridview` which user will be edited. In addition I handle the event RowsAdded of gvCondition so that display a default value in datagridview when user adding a new row.

When I add this col to my dgvCondition, and then add a row on it. It always show a empty cell except I select a value by myself. I tried to debug this app, and I found that code `cell.Value = lstParameterDataSource[0].Value;` didn't work. The cell's Value is always null.

What is going on? I want it show a default value when UI show. How can I implement this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(this.dgvCondition.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[0])).Value= lstParameterDataSource[0].Value;
```

let me know if u help this.